# Rails 3 + Heroku: cannot load such file -- test/unit/testcase (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm having the following error when running the console in heroku (`heroku run console`...). The application is running without problems, but I seem to be unable to run the console because of this and in development I'm not having this issue.

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- test/unit/testcase (LoadError)
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/test_case.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/console/app.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application.rb:304:in `initialize_console'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application.rb:152:in `load_console'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:27:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '3.2.9'

gem 'oauth', '~> 0.4.4'
gem 'twitter', '~> 1.4.1'
gem 'sendgrid'
gem 'koala'

gem 'therubyracer', '0.10.2'
gem 'execjs'

# Rails 3.1 - Asset Pipeline
gem 'json'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  >= 3.2.3"
  gem 'coffee-rails', ">= 3.2.1"
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass'
end

gem 'coffee-script'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem "fog"
gem 'bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails', '0.3.1.10'

group :production do
  gem "heroku"
  gem 'pg', '0.13'
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'
  gem 'newrelic_api'
end

group :test do
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem "cucumber-rails"
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "capybara"
  gem 'culerity'
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "database_cleaner"
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :development, :grades, :test do
  gem "launchy"
  gem "mysql2"
  gem "letter_opener"
  gem "pry"
  gem "rails-erd"
end

gem "airbrake"
gem "authlogic"
gem 'awesome_print'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'dalli'

#gem "oink"
gem 'validates_timeliness', '~> 3.0.2'
gem 'hpricot'
gem "ruby_parser"
gem "prawn_rails"
gem "thin"
gem "nested_form", :git => "git://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git"
gem "meta_search"
gem "carrierwave"
gem "aws-s3"
gem "mini_magick"
gem 'will_paginate'
gem "spreadsheet"
gem "oauth-plugin", ">= 0.4.0.pre1"
gem 'flash_cookie_session'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'squeel'
gem 'rails_best_practices', :group => :development
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'taps', :group => :development
gem 'resque'
gem "audited-activerecord", "~> 3.0"
gem "lograge"
gem 'quiet_assets'
gem 'yajl-ruby', :require => "yajl"
gem 'switch_user'
```

I've got no idea why I'm getting this error. Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Same here. Looks like heroku has some issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Removing `test` in the `.slugignore` file works for me.

Comment: This will only work on some systems. Rails 3.2 expects Test::Unit to be available when you run `rails console`. Adding the `test-unit` to your Gemfile as mentioned below will fix the problem.

Answer (score 62):

With Rails 3.1.12 and Ruby 2.2.0 I had to add

```
gem 'test-unit'
```

to my `Gemfile`.

Comment: Same error, not on heroku, but it works anyway, thanks

Comment: Shouldn't there be another way to remove this dependency? What if the `test-unit` gem is not needed?

Answer (score 7):

Apparently Heroku has changed the way it interprets the `.slugignore` file.

In my case, I had `rpc` directory in `.slugignore` and it wiped out `rpc` *subdirectory* of one of the gems my app is depending on, which resulted in `LoadError`. I'm unsure Heroku made this change intentionally. Regardless of whether `.slugignore` is working as they expect, removing affecting line(s) from `.slugignore` should fix the issue for now.

P.S. I've raised a support ticket to Heroku on this.

**UPDATE:** As per Heroku support, there were some changes to `.slugignore` parsing to make it more consistent with `.gitignore`, and it is working as intended. The right way to only delete the top level directory is putting `/rpc` instead.

Comment: Hi, I'm running a rails 3.2.3 and getting the same `LoadError` with `fog`. I don't use `.slugignore`, but I'm still getting the error.  Another part of this issue, I don't think it's reading my `staging.rb` environment file properly as I get this notice just above the error: `You did not specify how you would like Rails to report deprecation notices for your staging environment, please set config.active_support.deprecation to :log, :notify or :stderr at config/environments/staging.rb` BUT I do specify it to :notify in my staging file.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This (with the addition of the update) is a better answer than the selected one.

Comment: The parsing of the `.slugignore` has been a moving target lately, especially today. Comments in the `.slugignore` (a line started with a # symbol) used to be fine, but now cause the deploy to completely crash, with the less than helpful "unrecognized error". Also the number of files being ignored was totally inaccurate earlier today, and now it appears to be entirely omitted from the output. In other words, use .slugignore with caution until things stabilize.

Comment: Correction, the ignored file count is now showing up much earlier (right after the push) in the output, which seems to suggest that the implementation has been changed (again).

Answer (score 2):

Removing test dir from .slugignore fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

Remove test dir from `.slugignore`

Answer (score 0):

We also ran into this issue today. I suspect something must have changed in Heroku's Ruby build pack.

For us it was a problem with prototype-rails trying to load `ActionView::TestCase` which in turn requires `test/unit/testcase`. The [patch](https://github.com/ennova/prototype-rails/commit/16f68a7529dea20372561188e2c6a721e0d305ae) is pretty simple and is available as a [fork](https://github.com/ennova/prototype-rails).

If you're using Bundler, you might want something like:

```
gem 'prototype-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/ennova/prototype-rails.git'
```

Answer (score -2):

I tried disabling multithreading (comment out config.threadsafe!) and that seems to work for now until heroku gets their act together.