# Cucumber not working when running rake cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I have no features in a test app that I downloaded. I have written no code yet. I ran `rake cucumber` to test if it is working correctly or not and it gave me the following errors.

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -S bundle exec cucumber  --profile default
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/ast/step.rb:80: warning: circular argument reference - name
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
cannot load such file -- test/unit (LoadError)
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/test_help.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/cucumber-rails-1.4.1/lib/cucumber/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/SE/bdd-tdd-cycle/rottenpotatoes/features/support/env.rb:7:in `require'
/home/user/SE/bdd-tdd-cycle/rottenpotatoes/features/support/env.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in `load'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in `load_code_file'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:184:in `load_step_definitions'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in `run!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Could someone tell me what's going on? 
And what is the solution to this problem? It should ideally output that there are no tests available and the 0/0 steps passed.

Comment: Probably duplicated with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828889/rails-3-heroku-cannot-load-such-file-test-unit-testcase-loaderror

Comment: Can you post the code from your rake file? It doesn't look like the problem is Cucumber necessarily. You are getting a circular reference for one of your vars.