# rails console giving error to add test-unit gem to gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting an error while running `rails console`:

> ```
> `require': Please add test-unit gem to your Gemfile: `gem 'test-unit', '~> 3.0'`(cannot load such file -- test/unit/testcase) (LoadError)
> ```

If I add this gem to my Gemfile then rails console works fine. But why does it keep asking me to add this gem to my Gemfile?

Rails version 3.2.2

Comment: probably because one of your flies requires 'test-unit' gem

Comment: I am having the same issue. I do not have any dependency in my Gem lock. I am also running rails 3.2. Hopefully it will disappear in rails 4.2

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828889/rails-3-heroku-cannot-load-such-file-test-unit-testcase-loaderror

Answer (score 1):

It's rails dependency: https://github.com/drapergem/draper/issues/690
Please read more about that: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9711